# Changing source dynamically in Video.js won't play in flash

Tags: html, flash, video.js

I'm making a playlist with mp4-files. The playlists is loaded dynamically and played through continuously with Video.js. It works fine as long as the flash fallback doesn't kick in. If flash is used it will play the first clip then change source and then finally freeze, one or two frames into the second clip. I'm not using any special flash player but the one integrated in Video.js. 
I've seen people around the web with the same problem but no answers. Is this a real problem or am I doing something wrong?

This is where i change the source:

```
thePlayer.addEvent("ended", function () {
    var vp = this;
    vp.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: getSource() });
    vp.load();
    vp.ready(function () {
        vp.play();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it is a bug. The workaround I've found is to make another call to play() when the event "loadeddata" is received, i.e.

```
thePlayer.addEvent("loadeddata", function () {
    thePlayer.play();
});
```